# How to merge three tables in Asp net Mvc?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created three tables in the sql and then I have merged this three tables together to view the all records in each table. And I have used to created this code in MVC Error has been displayed below.

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MedeilMVC_CLOUD.Models.Company'. A member of the type, 'CompanyID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

[image: Error]

```
//View Company
public ActionResult ViewCompany()
{
    var data = dp.Company.SqlQuery("select CompanyName,ShortName,Division,ContactPerson,Designation,Email,Address1,Address2,Pincode,Country,State,City,MobileNo,PhoneNo,PanNo,TinNo,GSTno,IECCode,C.CountryName,s.StateName,C.CountryCode,C.DialingCode from CompanyRegistration AS CR LEFT JOIN VAN_SETTING.[dbo].[Country] AS C ON CR.Country=C.CountryID LEFT JOIN VAN_SETTING.[dbo].[State] AS S ON CR.State=S.StateID ORDER BY CompanyID  DESC").ToList();
    return View(data);
}
```

Below Image

[image: error]

Comment: You have not shown your table definitions, but best guess is `ORDER BY CR.CompanyID`

Comment: not working @StephenMuecke .. same error

Comment: Include `CompanyID` in the `SELECT` clause as well. And if that is not working, show you table definitions

Answer (score 0):

The Error message indicates the model you are reading into, has a Property named CompanyID.

I have added CompanyID in the select below, see how that goes.

```
//View Company
public ActionResult ViewCompany()
{
    var data = dp.Company.SqlQuery("select CompanyID, CompanyName,ShortName,Division,ContactPerson,Designation,Email,Address1,Address2,Pincode,Country,State,City,MobileNo,PhoneNo,PanNo,TinNo,GSTno,IECCode,C.CountryName,s.StateName,C.CountryCode,C.DialingCode from CompanyRegistration AS CR LEFT JOIN VAN_SETTING.[dbo].[Country] AS C ON CR.Country=C.CountryID LEFT JOIN VAN_SETTING.[dbo].[State] AS S ON CR.State=S.StateID ORDER BY CompanyID  DESC").ToList();
    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the bellow code. After join you need to specify the key for relation.

```
  var data = dp.Company.SqlQuery("select CompanyName,ShortName,Division,ContactPerson,Designation,Email,Address1,Address2,Pincode,Country,State,City,MobileNo,PhoneNo,PanNo,TinNo,GSTno,IECCode,C.CountryName,s.StateName,C.CountryCode,C.DialingCode from CompanyRegistration AS CR LEFT JOIN VAN_SETTING.[dbo].[Country] AS C ON CR.Country.Id=C.CountryID LEFT JOIN VAN_SETTING.[dbo].[State] AS S ON CR.State.Id=S.StateID ORDER BY CompanyID  DESC").ToList();
```

Comment: mssql cannot call methods on int